# Only the first MySQL call works in a php page

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I have a PHP script where I need to call 3 mysql stored procedures. But for some reason only the one I call first gets displayed. This is the code:

```
$raceid = $_GET['raceId'];
$race = "CALL GetRace($raceid)";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($race))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($results);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $results;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$fastround = "CALL GetFastestRound($raceid)";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($fastround))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($results);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {   
        echo $results;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}    
$uitslag = "CALL GetUitslagByRaceID($raceid)";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($uitslag)) 
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($results);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        echo $results
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

In this case, only the $race results get displayed. But if I put for example the $fastround code above the $race code (or simply remove the $race code) the $fastround results get displayed.

I've made the code on my Windows machine with WAMP, and wanted to move it to a Linux environment for the production environment. Another weird thing is that it worked perfectly on WAMP.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures may return more than one result set, therefore you must loop over all of them before issuing your next statement [`mysql_store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) call.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Or maybe wive an example?